# Can We Add upto 150 Columns in mysql database single table

Tags: mysql, database

I want to add 150-160 Columns in my database table ( Single table ). currently i have splitted these columns into 4 tables and working with join method. but, what problems can we face while storing data if we add this much columns in a single table.

Comment: Just avoid using `select *` in such a big table. Your data packet will become unnecessary big and slow everything else down

Comment: Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html

Answer (score 1):

> "Can We Add upto 150 Columns in mysql database single table"

Yes, it is possible. [C.10.4 Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html)

> **MySQL has hard limit of 4096 columns per table**, but the effective maximum may be less for a given table.
>
> The internal representation of a **MySQL table has a maximum row size limit of 65,535 bytes**, even if the storage engine is capable of supporting larger rows. BLOB and TEXT columns only contribute 9 to 12 bytes toward the row size limit because their contents are stored separately from the rest of the ro